# Call C function in swift3 fork(), system()

Tags: c, swift3.2

How to call fork() and system() in swift?

var pid = fork() // Error: Missing argument for parameter #1 in call

var r = system() **//Error: fork()' is unavailable: Please use threads or posix_spawn*()**

Tried

```
var param: Int8
var s = system(&param)
```

as well but it is giving different error - **'system' is unavailable in Swift: Use posix_spawn APIs or NSTask instead.**

I tried to use posix_param.
But getting another error
here is my code:-

```
var pid: pid_t

var status: Int32
posix_spawn(&pid, "", nil, nil, [], nil);
waitpid(pid, &status, WEXITED);
if pid >= 0 {
    return true

}
```

**Errors:** 
1) Address of variable 'pid' taken before it is initialized.
2) Address of variable 'status' taken before it is initialized.

Objective C version of this code which is working.

```
int pid = fork();
if(!pid){
    exit(0);
 }
 if(pid>=0)
  {
     return YES;
  }
```

[Here](https://github.com/sat2eesh/ios-jailBroken/blob/master/JBroken.m)

Comment: Have you tried using posix_spawn or NSTask? It's telling you that `system`s is unavailable in Swift.

Comment: I am not getting how to use posix_spawn

Comment: @Thomas can you please help me here?

Comment: Have you tried initializing the variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

**After initializing pid to -1 and status to 0.**

For **jailbroken** device pid value is greater than 0 whereas for **non jailbroken** device pid value remains unchanged.

Comment: Hi, could you share the code of your working implementation? Did you use the code from the question?